# Drools planner: changing SimpleScore to HardAndSoftScore

Tags: drools, n-queens, drools-planner, optaplanner

I am toying with drools planner as eventually I need to shape a rostering solution. I started from [Drools Planner user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html), I succeeded in running the examples in Eclipse.

Trying to understand the differences between the simple and the HardAndSoft score types, I am trying to modify the NQueens example, changing the score from Simple to HardAndSoft.

I did as follows:

1. In the nqueensSolverConfig.xml I set `<scoreDefinitionType>HARD_AND_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>`.
2. In the NQueens.java:

   - I set `public class NQueens extends AbstractPersistable implements Solution<HardAndSoftScore> {...}`
   - I changed SimpleScore related property and methods into corresponding HardAndSoftScore members:

   private HardAndSoftScore hsScore;

   public HardAndSoftScore getScore() {
       return hsScore;
   }

   public void setScore(HardAndSoftScore score) {
       this.hsScore = score;
   }

But when I run the solution I receive the following message:

```
"The scoreString (0) doesn't follow the 999hard/999soft pattern."
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 'll still have this in your solver config:

```
<termination>
  <scoreAttained>0</scoreAttained>
</termination>
```

Any score written in the solver config must be in the format of the score definition, so something like this:

```
<termination>
  <scoreAttained>0hard/0soft</scoreAttained>
</termination>
```

Note: you're probably off by looking at one of the "real" examples, such as course scheduling or nurse rostering, instead of N Queens.